# trying to close a pop up window after submitting a link on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a page in joomla that i am generating a pdf off of using the pdfmyurl service. to call the service you click a link. 
ie:

```
<a href="http://pdfmyurl.com?url=http://mywebsite.com/mypage&-R=0mm&-L=10mm&-s=Letter&--print-media-type&--footer-line&--filename=myfilename.pdf">click to generate pdf</a>
```

so you click a link on the main page which opens a "pdf-able" page in a popup window which then has a link to the above. (this is how joomla operates with printing pages).

this all works perfectly. but, i would like to close the popup when the link is clicked but AFTER the pdf is generated. if i use onclick="window.close();" method in the link the window closes before the pdf is generated.

i would like to solve this using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.open`, keep a reference to the window, and then go ahead and trigger `window.close()` when the PDF is finished loading (instead of the href). the only question is -- do you have any hooks to determine when the PDF has completed loading?

Reference: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html (mdn isn't working for me, but here's thelink: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open)

Comment: no hooks, the pdf loads into the browser as a download. i have window.open to open the window already... the only thing is that the window may lose focus after the browser download interface displays?

Comment: check this clever hack out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download. i'm not familiar enough to know if you can write back end code on joomla, though.

Comment: i think the problem is that i am not GET/POST-ing... its just a simple link to the pdfmyurl site.

Comment: well, you're still making a GET or a POST request for the PDF, the question is do you have control of that request (that returns the PDF)? if not, then you're not going to be able to take advantage of that hack.. :/

Comment: nope no control... will have to think of something else.. maybe a timer on the link click

Answer (score 0):

create a link or element with 'closePdf' id:

```
 $('#closePdf').click( function() { 
      $('#whateverYourPDFContainerIdIs').remove(); 
 });
```

Comment: the pdf is returned via browser download interface. there is no "container"